# Convert this long Excel date formula into VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have this Excel formula below;

```
DATE(LEFT(A1,3),MID(A1,6,1),MID(A1,7,1))
```

I would like to convert this Excel formula into a VBA user-defined function.

```
Public Function getDate(input_date As String)
    'code to convert DATE(LEFT(A1,3),MID(A1,6,1),MID(A1,7,1)) to VBA
End Function
```

This is tricky because there are functions used inside function parameters. Like LEFT used inside DATE.

EDIT: If possible, I would like to use the Excel formula directly inside the VBA function with minimal modification. Is it possible to do this in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really any different to what you are doing in Excel, at least as far as calling functions within functions:

```
Public Function getDate(input_date As String) As Date
    getDate = DateSerial(1900 + CInt(Left(input_date, 3)), _
                         CInt(Mid(input_date, 6, 1)), _
                         Cint(Mid(input_date, 7, 1)))
End Function
```

The `CInt` calls aren't strictly necessary, VBA will coerce the expressions returned from `Left` and `Mid` to numeric values, just as Excel does - but I like to explicitly show the conversions in these sort of statements.  But if you don't want them, you could use the following, which is basically identical to the Excel formula except for `DateSerial` instead of `DATE`.  (The VBA `Date` function just returns today's date.)

```
Public Function getDate(input_date As String) As Date
    getDate = DateSerial(1900 + Left(input_date, 3), Mid(input_date, 6, 1), Mid(input_date, 7, 1))
End Function
```

The addition of 1900 to the year is required because Excel handles that differently to VBA.  Excel treats a year of 20 as 1920, and a year of 104 as 2004.  VBA uses a windowing approach where years less than 30 are treated as 20yy, and years between 30 and 99 are treated as 19yy, and years greater than or equal to 100 are treated as 0yyy.

---

And, although I would **STRONGLY** discourage its use, you could use the exact same EXCEL formula within VBA using `Evaluate`:

```
Public Function getDate(input_date As String) As Variant
    getDate = Evaluate("DATE(LEFT(""" & input_date & """,3),MID(""" & input_date & """,6,1),MID(""" & input_date & """,7,1))")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted.

If possible, I would like to use the Excel formula directly inside the VBA function with minimal modification. This is because I already have many existing Excel formulas. Is it possible to do this in VBA?

Comment: @user3848207 Well, the equivalent to Excel's `DATE` is VBA's `DateSerial`.  Other than that, you can use the identical formula.  I'll update the answer to get rid of the (optional) `CInt`s.

Comment: @user3848207 - The formula has to have one other modification - because you are using a "yyy" year, the approach taken by Excel and VBA is different, which requires having to explicitly add 1900 to the entered date in order to get VBA to come up with the same answer as Excel would have.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this...

```
Public Function getDate(input_date As String)
    getDate = CDate(Evaluate("DATE(LEFT(" & input_date & ",4),MID(" & input_date & ",5,2),MID(" & input_date & ",7,2))"))
End Function

Sub Test()
MsgBox getDate("20170521")
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP has a weird date format.  I was just playing with the `Evaluate` and you will have to put the `input_date` within double-quotation marks in case the 4th and 5th characters aren't numeric.  (I've got no idea what sort of date format has 3-digit years and 1-digit month and days!  Maybe it is always 1 January.)

Comment: That seemed quite strange to me and that's why I made changes in the string functions. :)